# FluentPDO cant seem to find a way of doing OR clause

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So I have been using [FluentPDO](http://lichtner.github.io/fluentpdo/) quite a bit, BUT I can't seem to find a way of doing an OR clause, the where auto adds the AND and I don't see a way around it.

That is the type of SQL statement I need to create.

```
SELECT *
FROM `items` 
WHERE `item_var` LIKE '%test%' 
OR `item_text` LIKE '%test%' 
OR `item_int` LIKE '%test%' 
OR `item_select` LIKE '%test%' 
ORDER BY row_id
```

Comment: What if to write something like `where field = ? or field1 = ? or ...`, ahd then fill placeholders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the library, but after looking into the source, it doesn't seem like this is easily possible without placing your `OR` code into the `where()` call manually.

According to the [`where` method's docblock](https://github.com/lichtner/fluentpdo/blob/master/FluentPDO/CommonQuery.php#L27), it will prepend each successive clause with an `AND`.

It's not the most expressive code in the world, but it appears you would have to put your `OR`s in manually:

```
->where('(item_text LIKE "%test%" OR item_int LIKE "%test%" OR item_select LIKE "%test%")')
```

As long as you are using only `OR`, you might be able to clean it up a bit by putting them into an array and `implode()`ing them. Perhaps something like this would work:

```
$conditions = [
    'item_text LIKE "%test%"',
    'item_int LIKE "%test%"',
    'item_select LIKE "%test%"',
];

$orWhere = implode(" OR ", $conditions);
$query = $fpdo->from('items')->where("($orWhere)");
```

(**Edit**: grammar)

Comment: There's even a [feature request](https://github.com/lichtner/fluentpdo/issues/113).

Comment: Worked great, now i dont think that the "%test%" would be Escaped the characters so should i escape them before putting the value in there ?

Answer (score 1):

there is a method like this

```
$where['k1'] = $v1
$where[' ( k2 in (' . $v2 . ') or k3 in (?) )'] = $v3
```